# Feature with Icon, Text, and Line

Tags: openlayers-3

I'd like to have features in a vector source layer that each have an icon, text, AND a line.  I can get the icon and text to display but I can't get a line to draw.  Using a different geometry I can get a line with a label to draw but no icon.

Is this possible without creating another feature?  What geometry should I use for the feature?

Here's the code I'm using to draw an icon with text:

```
feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
));

feature.setStyle([
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
            opacity: 1.0,
            scale: 0.75,
            src: 'res/ship_a_flash.png',
            rotation: 30.0
        })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: feature.text,
            font: 'bold 20px Times New Roman',
            offsetY: -25,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgb(0,0,0)'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)', width: 1})
        })      
    })
]);
```

So now I want to add a single line from the first point.  I realize I need to add another point to the geometry so I tried MultiPoint and LineString like below.

```
feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.MultiPoint([
    ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([lon+1, lat+1], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')]
));

feature.setStyle([
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
            opacity: 1.0,
            scale: 0.75,
            src: 'res/ship_a_flash.png',
            rotation: 30.0
        })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: feature.text,
            font: 'bold 20px Times New Roman',
            offsetY: -25,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgb(0,0,0)'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)', width: 1})
        })      
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            width: 2,
        })      
    })
]);
```

I was hoping that the first point would be used for the Icon and Text and the 2 points would be used for the Stroke.  With MultiPoint, the feature (icon and text) are drawn twice - once at each point in the geometry.  With LineString, a line and text is drawn between the 2 points but the icon is not drawn.

It seems like I can either have an icon or a line in the feature, not both.

Comment: please be more specific about what techniques/methods you have used and attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following: Use a [geometry collection](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.GeometryCollection.html)  which contains a point and a line. Then use a [StyleFunction](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.html#StyleFunction) which gets the point and the line and returns two separate styles for them:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.GeometryCollection([
      new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
      new ol.geom.LineString([[0,0], [1E6, 1.5E6]])
  ]),
  ...
});

var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var geometries = feature.getGeometry().getGeometries();
    var point = geometries[0];
    var line = geometries[1];

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: point,
      image: ...,
      text: ...
    });

    var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: line,
      stroke: ...
    });

    return [iconStyle, lineStyle];
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8tzv9ms/11/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm sure a geometry collection is what I need, however, when I try to add text it is drawn for both the icon and the line.  I only want text for the icon.  I tried 2 different ways.  I added another Style [link](http://jsfiddle.net/p8tzv9ms/4/) and I also tried adding text to the iconStyle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/p8tzv9ms/7/).  Same result both times.  Any suggestions here?

Comment: Here's a simpler [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8tzv9ms/8/) showing text drawn for both the line and icon.  Any thoughts for how to get rid of the text on the line?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the example. The problem was getting the point and line. Both were `undefined` in the previous example.